# Cannot set value for the <comment> and <p> element with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, paragraph

I am using for Watir and run into problems of setting a value for

element.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div comment-editor-area="" class="comment-editor-area" contenteditable="true">
   <comment>    
       <p> "value goes in here"
          <br>
       </p>
 </comment>
</div>
```

I get undefined method "set" when I use:

```
 browser.element(:xpath, "//*[@id='comment-editor']/div/div/comment/p" ).set "Value"
```

Can anyone help?

**Error message:**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for #<Watir::HTMLElement:0x..fdae41aef064b3f16    located=false selector={:xpath=>"//*[@id='comment- editor']/div/div/comment/p"}>:Watir::HTMLElement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 workarounds.

**Using send_keys:**

Using `send_keys` seems to allow sending keys to the `div` element:

```
browser.div.send_keys 'Value'
```

Would add text to the div:

```
<div comment-editor-area="" class="comment-editor-area" contenteditable="true">Value
  Value
  <comment>    
    <p> "value goes in here"
      <br>
    </p>
  </comment>
</div>
```

Assuming you meant to replace the existing value, you could do:

```
browser.div.send_keys [:control, 'a'], :delete, 'Value'
```

Which would give the following:

```
<div comment-editor-area="" class="comment-editor-area" contenteditable="true">
  Value<br>
</div>
```

Unfortunately trying the same on the p element does not seem to work. It seems that this solution is only useful when sending keys to the first contenteditable element (and not its children).

(Note: The above was tested using Firefox. You might get different results from other browsers.)

**Using execute_script:**

An alternative would be to change the p element's text through javascript:

```
paragraph = browser.element(:xpath, "//*[@id='comment-editor']/div/div/comment/p" )
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTHML = "Value";', paragraph)
```

Which would give:

```
<div comment-editor-area="" class="comment-editor-area" contenteditable="true">
  <comment>    
    <p>Value</p>
  </comment>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Justin, Thanks for your help. I decided to try the first approach. Although at the beginning I was getting an error that argument[0] does not exist, I investigated more about that error... and... I found an article written by you :) [link] http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/passing-watir-elements-to-execute_script/

Comment: So I used this approach and it worked: `code`script = <<-JS
          return arguments[0].innerHTML = 'new value';
      JS
      paragraph = browser.element(:xpath, "//*[@id='comment-editor']/div/div/comment/p" )
      browser.execute_script(script, paragraph) `code`

Comment: Sorry about the typo. It is fixed now.